Streaming when doing computations with abstract term rewriting systems?
Computation models such as interaction nets can represent any computation as they are Turing complete.
However, I have been investigating their practical implementations, and I'm wondering if there's a notion of streaming or online algorithms for abstract term rewriting-based computations.
In general I'm pretty familiar with the literature (all of lafont and mazza's stuff), so I figured it's worth asking here
